# Download Kendo latest version using Upgrade Wizard

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I couldn't be able to use Kendo grid Excel export functionality. When I have search on internet, I found the issue happened because I'm using old Kendo version. I'm try to download the latest 2015 version but while clicking on "Download" button I am getting the below error message. Moreover I couldn't able to find 2015 in the drop down list. Please help me how I resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in to your Telerik Control panel and download the newest version, then you will be able to go through the upgrade process